# c++ what are the header files to include for using CP_UTF8 and WideChartoMultiByte

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Which header files do I have to include to use CP_UTF8 and WideChartoMultiByte

I am getting errors that they are not in scope.

I am working on Codeblocks in Linux (Debian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WideChartoMultiByte is a windows API. Maybe you should use `std::codecvt`.

Note that there is a know issue about `partial` on both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2007-04/msg00137.html) and [VC](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782724/the-codecvt-facet-returns-ok-when-not-all-characters-are-converted). I just stuck on them few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

That's just `<windows.h>`.